# C# Comparison shorthand

Tags: c#, comparison, shorthand

I have this code:

```
    if (y == a && y == b && y == c && y == d ...)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Is there some form of shorthand so that I can rewrite it as something like this?

```
    if(y == (a && b && c && d ...))
    {
        ...
    }
```

The functionality should be exactly the same. I'm just looking for something that looks less confusing.

**EDIT** Sorry for not clarifying, all the variables are integers. I'm looking for a shorter way to ensure that `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, ... all equal `y`.

Comment: Did you mean &&?  The answers people are giving seem to assume you meant "y == a || y == b ||..." which is to say that you are testing y to see if it is one of many possible values, but in fact the code you wrote is testing to see if ALL the possible values are equal to y.  If you meant && then it seems you are just testing that (y == a == b == c ...) which could be made easier to read with some method like "AreAllEqualTo(y, new T[] { a, b, c, d, ... })" that checks to make sure that the collection values are all equal to y.

Comment: By the way, your second code block does work normally in C#. I don't know what answer are you looking for.

Comment: Why not just y == a == b == c == d

Comment: @deadlock, while that second code block may be syntactically correct, I'm pretty certain it's semantically incorrect :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, I am assuming he is comparing booleans.

Comment: @Rob: You're comparing a boolean to an integer? Edit: Even if you're just comparing booleans, it's still dangerous -- what if the compiler evaluates `true == true == false == false` as `(true == true) == (false == false)`? You shouldn't rely on the order of evaluation like this.

Comment: @Lambert Ah yes, good point, kinda had a brain fart with the comparing of ints/bool there.

Comment: All of the variables are integers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest you're going to get (without implementing your own kind of mechanism):

```
if (new[] { a, b, c, d }.All(value => y == value))
    // ...
```

Comment: Ah... The beauty of LINQ.  It just never ends. :-)

Comment: Ah... the wastefulness and inefficiency of LINQ. It just never ends. :-)

Comment: As written, with `All`, it checks that *every* element is `y`. I think you meant `Any`. However, you can eliminate the lambda by using `.Contains(y)` (this is what I did in my answer).

Comment: @Bryan; It should be checking that _every_ element is y, as per the OP's example

Comment: @Lambert: For those of us who are just learning LINQ, should we take your comment as a cautionary "Avoid LINQ at all costs" or just "Don't use LINQ in every situation?"

Comment: @JYelton: As always, it depends on what you’re doing. If you’re trying to write high-performance real-time code, then you should have second thoughts about using LINQ. But in 99.99% of normal cases, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, there isn't anything that will simplify your code without outweighing the readability benefits with a big performance penalty.

---

Edit: **High-performance solution**

If you're desperate enough to try a high-performance solution, here's one:

(Update: Apparently I was wrong in thinking you can use generics with varargs; you apparently can only hard-code the types. So I changed the type below to `int` instead, but the same code applies.)

```
static bool AllEqual(int value, __arglist)
{
    for (var ai = new ArgIterator(__arglist); ai.GetRemainingCount() > 0; )
    {
        var next = __refvalue(ai.GetNextArg(typeof(int).TypeHandle), int);
        if (!value.Equals(next)) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then try calling it with:

```
//...
bool equal = AllEqual(1, __arglist(1, 1, 1));
```

Warning: People will probably yell at you for doing this, so use it at your own risk. :)

Comment: There may be something that makes the intention clearer, though.

Comment: Not really... even making a paramarray method that makes things clearer is still wasteful, since it would create a new array on every call. The *only* fast method I can think of is making a true varargs method (with `ArgIterator`), but that's more trouble than it's worth. (Note: This would be *much* easier in a language with better template and/or macro support, like D or Scheme/Lisp.)

Comment: @deadlock: Haha thanks... I actually write controversial code like this a lot, to get all the possible performance out of C#. :]

Comment: @Lambert, I wish I were that geeky!! ;]

Comment: @deadlock: funny, sometimes I wish I was less geeky... ;)

Comment: The params array solution is not slower. It allocates an array on the heap while this solution here does basically the same thing on the stack. It comes out the same. (I’m happy to be proven wrong with some real measurements.)

Comment: @Timwi: You *do* know that heap allocations are generally slower than stack allocations, right?

Comment: @Lambert: No, I don’t know that. Are they? Can you demonstrate that they are? (Of course they are in C and other unmanaged native code, but we’re talking about CLR-managed memory.)

Comment: @Timwi: Stackalloc is O(1), but heap allocation speed depends on the current state of the program, since it sometimes invokes the GC, and since how long it takes for the GC to walk the memory depends on how much memory is already allocated and how many objects are still alive. While heap allocations *can* reach stack allocations if the GC doesn't have any work to do, they get *much* slower if the GC has to perform significant collections... just try looping inside a program, and testing which is faster. (Just make sure your program already has objects on the heap, to make the GC do some work.)

Comment: @Timwi: [Here's just one link](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/15/improving-performance-through-stack-allocation-net-memory-management-part-2.aspx) I found on this issue... let me know if you need more.

Comment: @Lambert: Heap allocation is also O(1). You are acting as if the garbage collector runs with every heap alloc, which is of course not the case. Garbage collection can happen at any time; even in the middle of a stackalloc (because some *other* thread triggered it). I think we can safely disregard GC as a continuous background noise that affects every operation equally. (I don’t see the relevance of the link you gave. It just explains how to use stackalloc; it doesn’t give any performance measurements or comparisons.)

Comment: @Timwi: It's not O(1), it's nondeterministic. For starters, heaps are O(log n) complexity when removing elements, so a regular heap won't be O(1). Secondly, the allocation speed *depends* on the current memory state of the program, whereas a stack allocation is *truely constant-time* (it's really nothing more than a pointer increment, and it *never* invokes the GC). So stack allocations are naturally faster than heap allocations, although in the best-case scenario, it's conceivable that they'd be at the same speed.

Comment: @Lambert: LOL! Way to go for major misunderstanding! [Heap memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation) has *nothing at all* to do with [heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). In the CLR managed heap, allocation is *truly constant-time* too. The fact that 0.00001% of the time the GC may be running has absolutely no practical bearing on this, but even if it did, like I said it would have *exactly the same bearing on stack allocation.* Now I suggest you stop arguing and generate some actual numbers to demonstrate your case.

Comment: @Timwi: Except that your 0.00001% is actually somewhere around 1%-5% on average...

Comment: @Timwi: "Now I suggest you generate some actual numbers to demonstrate your case." ---> The problem is, if you're not already convinced, I don't think you're going to be convinced with numbers either. But just because you asked (I honestly wasn't going to waste time on this otherwise), try running [this example](http://ideone.com/x9rQH) on your computer a few times. It may run out of memory because it's random, but in the cases when it doesn't, I ask you in return that you **post your numbers** here. I got 421 ms for the heap and 31 ms for the stack. (Good luck, you'll need it.)

Comment: @Timwi: Since you like empirical evidence so much, here's *four more consecutive runs of my program* (heap, stack): (1139, 62); (5913, 327); (203, 16); (3479, 27).
How is your computer doing? Supporting your claims I hope? Or, if not, are you going to claim that I'm somehow "cheating" or that this isn't a fair comparison?

Comment: @Lambert: You really think that *every 20th object you allocate* invokes the garbage collector? If that is true, can you provide a reference for that claim? — Regarding the code you linked to, what does that have to do with this answer here? It uses neither arrays nor __arglist. Are you trying to win an argument by shifting goalposts?

Comment: @Timwi: It relates to heap allocations versus the stack, disproving your very argument that they're nearly equal in performance. Since you actually asked me to write a program, you should really run this and tell me your results... *after* you do that, if you still think I'm wrong, I'll write another program for you that compares arglist with paramarray side-by-side, but you first need to run this one.

Comment: @Timwi: "You really think that every 20th object you allocate invokes the garbage collector?" --> If your program is starting anew, no. If you've got a complex tree already in your memory, yes. My point is that heap allocation time is **nondeterministic** and can take a long time, whereas stack allocations are deterministic and constant-time.

Comment: @Timwi: To quote yourself: **LOL!!** **Way to go for major misunderstanding!** 5% time in GC means that 5% of your application's work time is in the GC, *not* that 5% of the allocations result in a collection!!

Comment: Now that I’ve actually tried this solution, I’m downvoting it because it doesn’t compile. “A method with vararg cannot be generic.” Furthermore, the `IComparable<T>` constraint is completely redundant (did you mean `IEquatable<T>`?).

Comment: @Lambert: Now that I’ve *actually tried it* (since you’re so persistent), here are *my* results for 10 runs of the *actual code we’re discussing*: `Stack=795, Heap=43, Stack=793, Heap=35, Stack=784, Heap=34, Stack=788, Heap=31, Stack=788, Heap=37, Stack=785, Heap=35, Stack=793, Heap=31, Stack=785, Heap=30, Stack=807, Heap=33, Stack=777, Heap=34`

Comment: @Lambert: Once again, can you provide a source for your claim that .NET programs spend 5% of their time in GC?

Comment: @Timwi: Yes, the `IComparable` should be `IEquatable`, I hope you had fun catching the typo and downvoting it. Secondly, your results don't agree with mine, and I don't know what you did but you definitely didn't run it right. *Can you even explain* why the stack might be slower than the heap?

Comment: @Timwi: *Why are you missing my point??* I'm saying that the GC **can** take up 5% of the time, *not* that it **necessarily** does that. Why are you completely ignoring this?

Comment: @Timwi: [Have you ever heard of midlife crisis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/04/41281.aspx)? Do you need more links to prove to you that programs can even spend 90% of their time in GC in worse cases?

Comment: @Lambert: I don’t know why I’m missing your point, maybe you need to make it clearer. But beside that, you are also ignoring my point that garbage-collection happens all the time, and thus both scenarios are equally affected. — [Here is the program I used to generate the above output.](http://ideone.com/alAzl) I suspect that any difference between heap and stack allocation are completely irrelevant compared to the overhead of using the (probably unoptimised) arglist iterator compared to the (easily jittable) array access. So the whole discussion here is moot.

Comment: @Timwi: You told me to write a program proving that heap allocation is slower than stack allocation, and I did -- and you failed to look at it... so I hope you don't actually expect me to look at your code. Furthermore, I made that^ point crystal clear, and if you're missing it then I just can't explain it better, sorry. I'm just tired of discussing this; I've got [home]work to get to, so I'll just stop here.
Thanks for pointing out the typo about generics and IEquatable, but I'm not going to bother testing anything else, whether you're right or me. Have fun with your heap allocations.

Comment: @Lambert: I’m still going to keep the downvote until you remove the phrasing “high-performance solution” from the answer, which I’ve shown to be false.

Answer (score 3):

*Slightly* more readable (in my opinion) is:

```
if ((y == a) && (y == b) && (y == c) && (y == d) ...)
```

but I don't believe there's anything in the base language for this.

If you really *want* something like what you propose, that's what functions are for, something like:

```
if (isSetToAll (y, a, b, c, d, ...))
```

but you might want to be careful on the performance front.

---

One thing *may* be of use to you if that's being done in a loop where `a/b/c/d/...` are invariant (in other words, where only `y` is changing).

Check the equality for the invariants outside the loop:

```
if ((a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d) ...)
```

because, if that's not the case, then `y` can never be equal to all of them. Then, inside the loop, just do:

```
if (y == a)
```

The fact that you already know that all the non-`y` variables are equal to each other means that you only need to check `y` against one of them.

But, since I haven't seen your complete code, I'm not sure if it will be useful to you.

---

I should mention that, while verbose, there's nothing actually unreadable about your original code, especially if it's formatted nicely. Even the behemoth:

```
if ((y == a) && (y == b) && (y == c) && (y == d) &&
    (y == e) && (y == f) && (y == g) && (y == h) &&
    (y == i) && (y == j) && (y == k) && (y == l) &&
    (y == m) && (y == n) && (y == o) && (y == p) &&
    (y == q) && (y == r) && (y == s) && (y == t) &&
    (y == u) && (y == v) && (y == w) && (y == x))
{
    ...
}
```

is readable (though I'm not a big fan of terse variable names).

Of course, at that point, you may want to look into using arrays with loops rather than singular variables.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Stick with what you have.

Well, you could write a `public static bool AllEqual<T>(params T[] values)` (maybe with overloads for 2/3/4/5 operands to avoid the array creation), but I'm not sure it is worth it most times.

Comment: It's a bool from the southern US :-)

Comment: @Marc: See my implementation... varargs, but safe and fast. (Never mind the undocumented part...) :)

Comment: @Lambert/Marc: I saw `boool` before I read the comments. I considered rolling back the edit just so the comments make sense; sorry for being a nitpicker. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Assuming you're comparing strings

```
IList<string> valuesToCompare = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

if (valuesToCompare.Any(valueToCompare => valueToCompare != y)) 
       //If there is any value that is not equal to y
       //Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new[] { a, b, c, d }.Contains(y)
```

Comment: Won't that return true if _any_ of the values are equal to `y`? That would be the correct translation if the OP had used `||` but I think, for `&&`, _all_ of `a/b/c/d/y` have to be equal to each other, no?

Comment: This is a good way to calculate if(y == a || y == b || y == c ...), so I'll keep this in mind. But I was actually looking for a way to calculate if(y == a && y == b && y == c ...)

Comment: @paxdiablo: You are right, I misunderstood the question. Checking that all elements of a sequence are the same is a much rarer operation than checking if any of them are equal to a value, and my eye skipped right past it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's impossible to be sure, I'd look at your overall code structure and see if there isn't just a better way to handle that whole area.

Any time you have a pattern that repeats like that, you will probably have to modify it a lot.  Chances are that you will need to add a new q==y or change something eventually.

A lot of people here were concerned with performance, but it's much more important to make sure your code is maintainable and understandable and properly factored.

As a total guess, I'd say that your a,b,c,d variables should all be a member of 4 different objects, a.x, b.x, c.x, d.x.  what do a,b,c,d represent?  They can't just be arbitrary numbers, they are prices or pixel locations or weights of elements--something!  I can't imagine a condition where you'd have exactly 4 and never 5 or 3 of something.

Anyway, whatever it represents, there are probably other things associated with it--a name, size, color, control index--whatever.

In general I'd look at a higher level for a fix to this problem.  I'd say at least a,b,c & d should be something defined outside the program, either in a data file or database.

Answer (score -1):

For **if (y == a && y == b && y == c && y == d)**, use:

<strike>if ( y == a == b == c == d)
{
   //code here
}</strike>

For **if (y == a || y == b || y == c || y == d)** and y is a simple type or string, use:

```
switch(y)
{
   case a:
   case b:
   case c:
   case d:
     //your code here
     break;

}
```

Comment: Your first example will not work.  For example, `y=false`, `a=false`, `b=false`.  `(y == a == b)` is going to return `false`, when it should return `true`.  `a==b` is true, but `y` is false, so the expression returns false.

Comment: Right. Parenthesis to the rescue, but that would also mean my first example will only work on comparisons that are exponents of 2.

Comment: Nope, even with that it won’t work. If `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` are all different, `(a == b) == (c == d)` will return `true`.

Comment: Ya, you'd have to go (a == b) && (b == c) && (c == d). Definitely not more readable than the original question.

Answer (score -3):

```
   bool  x=true ,y=true, z=true, p = true;

    if (x == (y == z == p)) //true

    x = false;
    if (x == (y == z == p)) //false
```

Comment: But if x, y, z, and p are all false, your code returns false when it should return true.

Comment: @Jim, please don't criticize unless you are sure of what you are saying. In our case, == works like &&. And both should do the same job here. Correct me.

Comment: @deadlock: If `x=false, y=false, z=false` then the desired result is `true`--they are all equal. But `(x == (y == z))` evaluates to `(x == (true))`, which evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @Jim, I am somehow certain that (y==z==p) evaulates to false when y,z,p equals to false. compile it, and try it. And tell me how did it go.

Comment: @deadlock: Yes.  `(x == (y == z == p))` evaluates to `false` when x,y,z,p are `false`.  But the OP wanted a replacement for `(x == y && x == z && x == p)`, which evaluates to `true` when x,y,z,p are `false`.  So your solution is not a working replacement.

Comment: @Jim, (x == (y == z == p)) evaluates to true when x,y,z,p are false. I am sure of that.

Comment: @deadlock: interesting. I stand corrected in that case. Note, however, that `(x == y == z)` evaluates to `false`, so the solution isn't a general replacement for the construct.  Also, try `x=true`, `y=true`, `z=false`, `p=false`:  `(x == y == z == p)` evaluates to `true` when it should be `false`.