# Check all numbers are equal

Tags: performance, algorithm

What is the best way to check that all numbers in the array (or list) are equal?

I think the solution as a loop that seek for the first unequal element ist maybe efficient, but not so elegant or readable. Any solutions in one line?

Comment: There's nothing more elegant.

Comment: For example in c# (maybe as linq).

Comment: "For example in c#": `array.All(x => x == array.First())` That will return `true` for an empty array. If you don't want that, make it `array.Any() && ...` .

Comment: @Ani array.TrueForAll you wanted to say ;)

Comment: Similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719227/c-comparison-shorthand

Comment: @Elalfer: That's fine too - that's a static method on `Array`; what I suggested is a LINQ extension-method.

Comment: Elegant in python: min(x)==max(x)

Comment: @Max: That works in C# too: `x.Min() == x.Max()`, but it will throw if the sequence is empty.

Comment: `min(x)` have to iterate the whole array to find the minimal -- it is less efficient.

Comment: @Ani, arrrrrr, damn. you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any solution to this problem must run in Ω(n) time and make Ω(n) comparisons, since if this isn't the case for some sufficiently large array you wouldn't be able to look at all the elements to check that they have the same value.

Doing a linear scan of the array looking for any values different from the first one is perhaps the absolute best way to solve this problem.  It makes a total of (n - 1) comparisons, which asymptotically matches the lower bound, and is both elegant and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Some sort of C pseudocode

```
i = len(list) - 1;
while (list[i] == list[i+1] && i) i--;
return i == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not one line though in the right language, I'm sure you could get it to one.

**EDIT:** Since you said C#...

```
return list.Length > 0 && list[0] == list.Aggregate(list[0], (current, i) => current & i);
```

Comment: `int combined = 0xFF;` is not a good idea, but `int combined = list[0]` should be fine